# Can open bottom septic tank weaken the building foundation

Tags: walls, leak, foundation, septic

My building has a septic tank which is at the bottom of the groundfloor. Basically it's right underneath the building and it has open bottom.

I'm worried if this can weaken the soil (Clay ground) leading to weakening of building foundation.

Is it a problem ? if yes , what are the solutions we have to keep in mind.

Comment: So after all the questions yesterday, you now find out there's a septic tank under the building?

Comment: How old is the building?

Comment: I think you need to hire some professionals rather than asking tons of broad questions

Comment: No, not if you have a basement and the groundwater has raised above the original elevation it was designed for. Groundwater fluctuation has minimal effect on the spread footings, except overdrawn the groundwater that causing the soil to consolidate (settle).  I assume your building has a  footprint of 120'x40', for every day it releases 70 cf of wastewater, then assume the ground does not absorb any of the released water, the groundwater will raise 70*12/(120^40) = 0.175" per day, or 1' per 68 days. Please check with an engineer to relieve your anxiety.

Answer (score 0):

Without soil cores and information on elevation changes, we don't know if it's a problem or not. If it is a problem, you could install another septic tank away from the building. If you're sure it's open bottom, you could add one.

Comment: Soil is complete clay and it's plain land like it has farm fields near by. The ground water table is at 8 feet.

Comment: When you say , if its open bottom then I could add one ? what's the meaning , you mean to say that I could add one more septic tank below the current one and seal the bottom with concrete

Comment: @RaviMan We can't determine if there's a problem. If there is a problem, you could install a septic tank away from the house. You don't really have a septic tank, you have a septic pit. You could get someone to add a floor to it , making it a tank.

Comment: The problem is I don't have extra space either to have seperate septic tank but just wondering whether the septic pit would cause some issue like weakening the foundation

Comment: It's completely clay and it's part of river delta( Kaveri )

Comment: Please find soil cores here ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0djV.jpg )

Comment: Septic tank has come into use now with open bottom just wondering if there is anything else I can do like preventive steps or risk mitigating exercises ?